# Unable to save highscore of game using shared preferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Here is my code for game i use to save high score

```
SharedPreferences preferences = null;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    //Highscore.easyHigh = 0;

    Highscore.easyHigh = preferences.getInt("EasyScore", 0);
    Highscore.mediumHigh = preferences.getInt("MediumScore", 0);
    Highscore.hardHigh = preferences.getInt("HardScore", 0);
```

Now i set these values when player looses the game

```
editor = preferences.edit();
        if(level==1)
        editor.putInt("EasyScore", score);
        else if(level==2)
        editor.putInt("MediumScore", score);
        else if(level==3)
        editor.putInt("HardScore", score);
        editor.commit();
```

Highscore is my class storing public static int easy, medium , hard?

I get a null pointer exception but why does that happen?

Comment: You havent initialised `preferences` and `editor`..Do it after `setContentView()` in your code..

Comment: If you save your game values on `SharedPreferences`, everyone with a rooted device will be able to cheat on your game.

Answer (score 2):

Your preferences and editor values are not initalized, use this :

```
preferences = PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferenes(this);
editor = preferences.edit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent initialised `preferences` and `editor`..Do it after `setContentView()` in your code..

Do it like this..

```
preferences = PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferenes(this);
editor = preferences.edit();
```